# Amazon S3 Upload with Laravel Livewire 404

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-livewire

Everytime I tried to upload it gives me an error of

```
Error executing "HeadObject" on *BUCKET URL* AWS HTTP error: Client error: `HEAD *BUCKET URL* ` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response NotFound (client): 404 Not Found
```

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is, I set up everything in the .env file, IAM, S3, and S3 CORS configurations.

`$this->logo->storeAs('logos', $file_name, 's3');$this->logo->storeAs('logos', $file_name, 's3');`

This is what I'm using for my uploading, it works when I don't use s3.
My CORS Config

```
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*My Website*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
```

Comment: The error says the bucket was not found. Are you sure you put in the correct bucket name? And are you sure your credentials have permission to access it?

Comment: I have the correct bucket name, and created a user in my IAM with the AmazonS3FullAccess permission? Is there something I'm missing. Do I also need to configure the folders before trying to upload with destinations?